# Treat Two Columns as One

Tags: perl

Sample Text:

```
$ cat X
Birth Death Name
02/28/42 07/03/69 Brian Jones
11/27/42 09/18/70 Jimi Hendrix
11/19/43 10/04/70 Janis Joplin
12/08/43 07/03/71 Jim Morrison
11/20/46 10/29/71 Duane Allman
```

After Processing With Perl, column & sed:

```
$ perl -lae 'print "$F[2]_$F[3] $F[0]"' X | column -t | sed 's/_/ /g'
Name          Birth
Brian Jones   02/28/42
Jimi Hendrix  11/27/42
Janis Joplin  11/19/43
Jim Morrison  12/08/43
Duane Allman  11/20/46
```

This is the exact output I want. But the issue is, I do not want to use `column -t | sed 's/_/ /g'` at the end.

My intuition is that this can be done only with perl oneliner (without the need of sed or column).

Is it possible? How can I do that?

**P.S.** I have an awk solution (`awk '{print $3"_"$4" "$1}' X | column -t | sed 's/_/ /g'`)as well for this exact same result. However, I am looking for a perl only solution.

Comment: You can do `perl -lane '$name = join q{ }, @F[2..$#F]; print join q{ }, $name, $F[0]' file` but this assumes the name column always starts at column 3. Is that fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way

```
perl -wlnE'say join " ", (split " ", $_, 3)[-1,0]' input.txt
```

This limits the [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) to three terms -- first two fields obtained by normally splitting by the given pattern, and then the rest, here comprising the name.

It won't line up nicely as in the shown output.

---

If the proper alignment is a must, then there's more to do since one must first see the whole file in order to know what the field width should be.  Then the "one"-liner (command-line program) is

```
perl -MList::Util=max -wlne'
    push @recs, [ (split " ", $_, 3)[-1,0] ];
    END { 
        $m = max map { length $_->[0] } @recs; 
        printf("%-${m}s %s\n", @$_) for @recs
    }' input.txt
```

---

If an apriori-set field width is acceptable, as brought up in a comment, we can do

```
perl -wlne'printf "%-20s %s\n", (split " ", $_, 3)[-1,0]' input.txt
```

The saving grace for the obvious short-coming here -- what with names that are longer? -- is that it is only those particular lines that will be out of order.

Comment: With this code Birth is not on top of the birth date. In other words, The heading is not aligned properly. Please run my sample code to check the difference.

Comment: @blueray That was the question in the answer, whether the alignment is necessary since for that there has to be considerably more code -- must first see the whole file, so that we can decide the maximum length of the name so to be able to set the field width. Added that to the answer

Comment: not the prettiest one-liner but works. Hope it could be a little shorter.

Comment: @blueray yeah, agreed completely ... the problem is that: must first see all lines (full line of code), then need that max (full line of code), then need `printf` (full line of code).  Don't see how to cut that short ... will try :)

Comment: I just got a solution from https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/showthread.php?p=6112303#post6112303 which is `perl -l -a -e 'printf("%-20s %s\n", "$F[2] $F[3]", $F[0]);'`

Comment: @blueray Well, but that uses a fixed field width (20) -- what if just one name is longer? (Or what if all names are quite a bit shorter? Will look bad.)  But if that's OK then I just use `printf` in my first line (and don't need a `join` at all then!).  Let me know if you can estimate a cap on name length and I'll add that, as well

Comment: @blueray Btw, that "solution" isn't very solid --- what if a name has more than two words?

Comment: @blueray Added a variation that uses a fixed field width

Comment: @blueray Oh, OK :)   (I did get a considerably shorter one --- that still computes the actual max width -- but it's ... uglier, and it's still two lines. So never mind)

Answer (score 1):

See if following one liner will be an acceptable solution

```
perl -ne "/(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)/, printf \"%-13s %s\n\",$2,$1" birth_data.dat
```

Input `birth_data.dat`

```
Birth Death Name
02/28/42 07/03/69 Brian Jones
11/27/42 09/18/70 Jimi Hendrix
11/19/43 10/04/70 Janis Joplin
12/08/43 07/03/71 Jim Morrison
11/20/46 10/29/71 Duane Allman
```

Output

```
Name          Birth
Brian Jones   02/28/42
Jimi Hendrix  11/27/42
Janis Joplin  11/19/43
Jim Morrison  12/08/43
Duane Allman  11/20/46
```

Comment: For some reason it returns empty strings in my machine.

Comment: @blueray -- did you specify proper filename with data? What you get if you issue command `perl -pe "" data_file`? What OS do you use?

Comment: `perl -pe "" X` output the exact dataset. I am using WSL with Windows.

Comment: @blueray -- I wrote and run/test code snippet in Window 10. In Windows perl command should be `perl -ne "perl code" data_file` and in Linux `perl -ne 'perl code' data_file`. I am not sure why you did not get filtered result -- as `perl -pe "" X` confirmed that perl reads and prints input to output.

Comment: By looking at your oneliner, I thought it would work. Not sure why it is not working on my machine.

Comment: @blueray -- try run `perl -ne "/(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)/; printf \"%-13s %s\n\",$2,$1" X`.

Comment: The code was tested with **Strawberry perl**. Hmm, WSL for Windows. I do not have any experience with it and not sure how it emulates Linux. You can try to run `perl -ne '/(\S+)\s+\S+\s+(.*)/; printf "%-13s %s\n",$2,$1' X` instead -- it might be that WSL uses Linux style quoting of the code.